# RabbitMQ throws an exception when sending to dead letter queue (DLQ) (maximum frame_size)

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-rabbit

When I got a message from the queue and if an exception was thrown, I wanted to get the message again.

So, I create my consumer with a [DLQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_letter_queue) queue:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        to-send-output:
          destination: to-send-event
          producer:
            required-groups:
              - to-send-event-group
        to-send-input:
          destination: to-send-event
          group: to-send-event-group
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 1
            requeueRejected: true
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          # Forever retry
          to-send-input:
            consumer:
              autoBindDlq: true
              dlqTtl: 5000
              dlqDeadLetterExchange:
              maxConcurrency: 300
              frameMaxHeadroom: 25000 # I added this as in the documentation
```

I added the property `frameMaxHeadroom: 25000` as it says in [the documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit#spring-cloud-stream-rabbit-frame-max-headroom), but it still does not work.

My `springCloudVersion="Hoxton.RELEASE"`.

My dependency:

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit"
...
}
```

In the repository [on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/blob/09c8b9bdc5a172b4034b32ff4d70b094ccb616b7/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/rabbit/properties/RabbitConsumerProperties.java#L112-L115), I see the `frameMaxHeadroom` property in the property file.

I see that [the code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/blob/361566458036979bbbfe4f5ed31df8d0854fd8de/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/rabbit/RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java#L513) reduces the stack trace by the value I set (from a variable `frameMaxHeadroom`). I expected that I wasn't decreasing the stack trace, but increasing the value for the headers for the consumer, as written in the documentation.  Why isn't it working as I wait?

Comment: The property is indeed there https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/blob/09c8b9bdc5a172b4034b32ff4d70b094ccb616b7/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/rabbit/properties/RabbitConsumerProperties.java#L112-L115 - maybe 25000 is still not enough? The default is only 5000 less.

Comment: @GaryRussell when I send msg, I stopped in `AMQCommand.class` and see on 109 line that `frameMax=131072` (it is not 20000 as in documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frameMax` is negotiated between the [AMQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) client and server; all headers must fit in one frame. You can increase it with the broker configuration.

Stack traces can be large and can easily exceed the `frameMax` alone; in order to leave room for other headers, the framework leaves at least 20,000 bytes (by default) free for other headers, by truncating the stack trace header if necessary.

If you are exceeding your `frameMax`, you must have other large headers. You need to increase the headroom to allow for those headers, so the stack trace is truncated further.

Comment: So, I can just reduce the header `x-exception-stacktrace`. And I can't increase the space for all the other headers. Is this true?

Comment: The frame_max is determined by the server - by the default the client sends 0 when negotiating - which means the negotiated size will be the max size configured on the server. According to this https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2012/11/breaking-things-with-rabbitmq-3-0/ (scroll down to `frame_max`) the default is 128kb but it can be increased on the server.

Comment: And how can I increase it?

Comment: I don't know - I don't see it here https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-items, but it does say `These variables are the most common. The list is not complete, as some settings are quite obscure.` - I suggest you ask the RabbitMQ folks on their `rabbitmq-users` Google group.